# Naive Question Related to Inequality for Comparing a Fixed Real Number and 1/$\infty$

Tags: calculus, limits, inequality

> Given any real number $a>0$, can I say
>   $$
> a>1/b
> $$
>   for $b=\infty$?

Here is my thinking: let $a>0$ be fixed, I see $$a>\lim_{b \to \infty}1/b=0,$$ hence, $a>1/b$ for $b=\infty$. Is my thinking correct?

Comment: How do you define $\frac 1\infty$?

Comment: @5xum, I simply put $1/\infty =0$

Comment: Well, if you **define** $\frac1\infty$ to be equao to $0$, then yes, for every $a>0$, it is true that $a>\frac1\infty$, in the same way as for every $a>1$, it is true that $a>1\cdot 1$...

Comment: @5xum, Thanks, but I kind of bothering the following thing: $0>0$ can this case happen?

Comment: of course not. $0>0$ is a false statement. But it can't happen in your case, since $a>0$...

Comment: @5xum, thanks!! I got that.

Comment: where are $a$ and $b$? Hypereals, reals, natural numbers, etc?

Comment: $a$ is real number, and $b$ is a straight infinity (or I say $b$ lives in extended real line).

Comment: Your conclusion that a > limit 1/b = 0.  Is *absolutely correct*.  However as infinity is not a number any statement f($\infty$) = lim f(x) is meaningless gibberish, no matter how slick and tempting.  f($\infty$) simply doesn't mean anything.  And we don't need it as we can always simply refer to lim f(x).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to note that $\infty$ is **not a real number**. All real numbers are finite. Hence, the notation where $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and $a>0$ such that $$a>1/b$$ and $b=\infty$ is *not clearly defined*. Certainly this does not make sense if $b$ is meant to be a real number. However, there are ways to make it make sense if you *assign* it a meaning.

There are several ways you can do this, for example by looking at the so-called extended reals: $\mathbb{R}\cup\{-\infty,+\infty\}$. Under this system, a *definition* of $\frac{c}{\pm\infty}=0$ for $c\in\mathbb{R}$ is probably common.

If $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ with $a>0$, you are correct to say $\lim\limits_{b\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{b}=0$. In this case, it is true that $a>\lim\limits_{b\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{b}$.

A more advanced method to talk about "infinities" is to use so-called "nonstandard analysis" pioneered by Abraham Robinson. In these systems, you introduce "infinite" numbers and "infinitesimals" in a rigorous fashion.

Comment: Thanks, It is very helpful. :-)